# Выполнение ShellExec в установщике Inno Setup

Tags: pascal, inno-setup

Нужно выполнить одну команду после установки по определённым условиям. Привязался к *AfterInstall*, написал небольшую процедуру, в ней после некого набора операторов в конце концов выполняется такой:

```
line := '/k "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongorestore.exe" -d test-db "C:\Users\test\Desktop\database\test-db"';
ShellExec('', 'cmd.exe', line, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated,ResultCode);
```

Команда не выполняется, с жалобой на:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если я уберу аргумент *второго* пути из команды, и приведу её к такому виду:

> '/k "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongorestore.exe" -d test-db'

то всё сразу начинает работать, система определяет запускаемый процесс, и всё хорошо. Также, если убрать из второго пути кавычки(при условии, что в пути отсутствуют пробелы) то работа тоже корректна. Но, дело в том, что я не могу наверняка знать, будут ли в пути пробелы или нет, поэтому оборачиваю в кавычки любой путь. И, если, обернув путь к запускаемому процессу в кавычки я не получаю проблем, то, обернув путь аргумента процесса в кавычки, я вижу то, что отображено на скриншоте выше. Почему это происходит и как это излечить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, чтобы была возможность использовать несколько пар двойных кавычек в строке, следует также обернуть всю строку в двойные кавычки:

```
line := '/k ""C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongorestore.exe" -d test-db "C:\Users\test\Desktop\database\test-db""';
```